# $L^1$ interesting property

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is it true that if $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is in $L^1 (0,1)$ and 
$$\int_0^t f(s) ds = 0, \forall \ t\in [0,1]$$, then $f(t) =0$ almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes, it certainly is true.

Comment: Why is it true? Can you give some details. We do not know that f is positive.

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate the integral with respect to $t$ almost everywhere, which would imply that $f = 0 $ a.e. A quick way to see this is via [Lebesgue points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point). If $x\in (0,1) $ is a Lebesgue point of $f$, then
$$
\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{2h}\int\limits_{x - h}^{x + h} f(t) dt = f(x).
$$
The integral average equals $0$ since it is the difference of integrals over $[0,x+ h]$ and $[0, x- h]$ and both equal $0$. Hence $f(x) = 0 $ whenever $x$ is a Lebesuge point of $f$. Now, if $f\in L^1(0,1)$ almost all points $x\in(0,1)$ are Lebesgue points of $f$, hence the claim.